# Change path in file batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd, exe

I have a problem with this bat:

```
@echo off

set CD1OLD=%CD%
cd /d %~dp0


%CD%\xxx.Http.Client.exe http://localhost:8081/aaa/comparer/aa/base/aa/compare >     debug_aaa_base.xml
echo.
%CD%\xxx.Http.Client.exe http://localhost:8081/aaa/comparer/aa/complessi/aa/compare > debug_aaa_complessi.xml
echo.
echo ****** LANCIO xxxx ******
%CD%\Lancio_xxxx.bat
echo.
```

After this piece of code, I need to run this:

```
echo ****** SPOSTA FILES ****** 
%CD%\Elaborazione_aaa_Spostamento_files.exe
cd /d %CD1OLD%
```

but it's not working.. It seems that the first code changes his execution path while executing the code itself, giving problems with the second code block's execution..

In particular, if I remove this  line

```
%CD%\Lancio_xxxx.bat
```

everything works fine. But I need to run that line too!

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance

best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that if you just call a .bat from another one, the command processor won´t return to the caller. The calling batch does not resume execution, the "call" is like a simple `goto` that goes to the referenced batch file.

If you replace

```
%CD%\Lancio_xxxx.bat
```

with

```
call %CD%\Lancio_xxxx.bat
```

then after execution of that batch file, the commands after that `call` line will be executed too, which seems to be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try the commands PUSHD and POPD around the line which executes Lancio_xxx.bat

These commands save and restore the current directory respectively

See the following links for details:

http://ss64.com/nt/pushd.html

http://ss64.com/nt/popd.html

Comment: The problem is not a changing working directory. When running batch scripts from a batch script you must use `call` (synchronous) or `start` (asynchronous), otherwise control won't go back to the parent script and the remaining commands from that script won't be executed.